# Rsync incredibly slow in Cygwin - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, backup, cygwin, rsync

I am trying to back up my C: and D: drives (each 1 TB, C: has around 210 GB of data on it, D: has around 345 GB on it) onto a 3 TB external HDD using Cygwin in Windows 8.

I am doing this with `rsync.exe -avz --progress /cygdrive/c/ /cygdrive/f/Backup/c/` and I let it run over night and just checked it and it has only copied around 33 GB. That is 33 GB in about 6 hours. I had done it the night before using `cp -rf` and it finished overnight (that is around 210 GB in the same amount of time or less). I chose to redo it using `rsync` so that I future backups would not take as long.

Am I doing something wrong? Does `rsync` not work well in cygwin? I thought it was the same performance as `cp`.

If I did want to go back to using `cp`, what is the best command to duplicate `rsync` (all I want to do is to copy the file if it is not there or if the source file is newer).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure WHY, but I found a solution [on the cygwin mailing list archive](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-07/msg00443.html).

Adding the `-W` argument to rsync took my transfer speed from 200kBps to 1.5MB/s.

Comment: Thank you, that -W option fixed it for me too. It's indeed five or six times faster.

Comment: Strange, on my Windows 10 machine the `-W` flag to cygwin rsync.exe actually makes it run even slower!

Comment: @mcandre, if you are using ssh, the `-W` flag would likely be slower. Are your source and destination both local?