# Very slow file comparison when running Rsync

Tags: rsync, wsl2

Something is wrong with rsync speeds in one scenario.

I sync files from a SSD disk to an exFAT VeraCrypt container on an HDD (entire HDD is encrypted with VeraCrypt, the encrypted container is formatted in exFAT) on Windows using WSL 2. There is fast CPU and disks, speeds >50 MB/s.

### rsync

rsync reported a total of 17158 files + 2431 dirs, and total size 2 GB. There should be 78 files transferred with the size of 40 MB.

1. Dry run: **11m 45s**

   ```
   wsl rsync -rtvih --progress --stats --delete %SRC% '%DEST%' --modify-window=2  --filter 'merge ./.rsync-filter-work' -n
   ```
2. Actual run: **13m 16s** (while the file list was built in 1m 50s)

   ```
   wsl rsync -rtvih --progress --stats --delete %SRC% '%DEST%' --modify-window=2  --filter 'merge ./.rsync-filter-work' --info=progress2 --no-inc-recursive
   ```

#### For comparison

3. Another Windows tool compared these folders in **0m 50s**! It worked without any filter, so it checked 201k files and 60k folders. Over 12 times faster. Sending the files would take at most a couple of seconds.
4. I also send the same files to a remote Linux machine using:

   ```
   rsync -rtvih --progress --stats --delete --compress -e %SSH% %SRC% '%USER%'@%HOST%:'%DEST%' --filter 'merge ./.rsync-filter-work' -n
   ```

and this dry run takes only **1m 30s**.

5. If I do dry run from step (1) to a non-existing folder on the same VeraCrypt drive, it runs pretty fast. So something must be slowing down reading target file list.
6. `wsl find . -iname xyz` runs in **2m 0s**, so wsl2 is probably not the culprit.

#### Questions

1. Is there anything to improve the performance in my rsync command?
2. What is slowing down local folder comparison in steps 1 and 2?

Comment: Sounds like a timestamp issue to me. Meaning, I don’t believe a dry run would factor in timestamp differences between the two machines. But when the command actually runs, a mismatch with timestamps _might_ make the process slow down. Also, look at [this other Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/905415/167207) that suggest using the `-W` flag. According to the [Rysnc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), `-W, --whole-file copy files whole (w/o delta-xfer algorithm)`. Why that would help? No idea. But worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for help, but to no avail. Removing `--modify-window` did not speed up (and files started showing due to exFAT's 2-seconds precision of timestamp). Adding `-W` changed nothing (not sure if it would in dry mode).

Comment: I wonder if syncing via the virtual network (with the help of msys2 rsync on the Windows side) makes it a bit faster (the compatibility layer will become the bottleneck, I suppose).

Comment: You definitely need `--modify-window=2` when writing to a FAT filesystem. Why have you included `--no-inc-recursive`? Unless you have a very specific situation that isn't described here you don't need that. The `--whole-file` (`-W`) flag is already set because `rsync` sees this as a local on-machine file copy.

Comment: @roaima I added `--no-inc-recursive` to see total progress % :). It's in the actual #2 command (not dry-run #1 command), and does not impact total duration that much. If only the duration wouldn't be awful at the beginning ;).

Comment: ok, I can understand that. The problem is that because you've specified it, `rsync` has to determine the set of files to copy before it can start copying any of them - hence the delay

Comment: @roaima Yes I know it. But honestly - copying 78 files that total 40 MB should not impact the duration at all ;).

Comment: @TomYan I would prefer to not install msys2 only to fix this problem. Thanks for suggestion. though.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a bit of a guess here, but based on this statement ...

> Another Windows tool compared these folders in 0m 50s!

... it sounds like the source directory may be a Windows folder (e.g. `/mnt/c/...`, etc.)?

If that's the case, then realize that WSL2 is notoriously slow when accessing Windows drives specifically.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/11810933) for more details, but as a comparison from that answer:

> I've seen a `git clone` of a large repo (the WSL2 Linux kernel Github) take 8 minutes on WSL2 on a Windows drive, but only seconds on the root filesystem.

The problem is much worse for small file reads, in my understanding, although I can't recall having done any benchmarks with large files.

Also, you mention:

> If I do dry run from step (1) to a non-existing folder on the same VeraCrypt drive, it runs pretty fast. So something must be slowing down reading target file list.

I have a theory on this that I haven't had a chance to test yet.  When syncing to an existing directory, `rsync` will automatically use its "delta-transfer algorithm" to send only the changed portions.  This goes to the "small file reads/writes" issue from above.

You might try using the `--whole-file` option to disable delta-transfers.

But the best solution (assuming this is your problem) is likely to use WSL1 whenever accessing files on Windows drives, assuming that you can access the VeraCrypt container from it.

I actually keep a distribution running on WSL1 primary for this reason -- For me, the issue is running a very large `s3sync`, and the performance on WSL1 is orders of magnitude faster on WSL1.

Comment: "_When syncing to an existing directory, rsync will automatically use its "delta-transfer algorithm" to send only the changed portions_" - no it doesn't. It only uses the delta algorithm when transferring across a network connection. For local transfers (i.e. both source and destination paths without `host:` or `host::`) it sets `--whole-file` and compression simply adds inefficiency

Comment: @roaima In WSL2, a connection to a "local" (host) Windows drive is through the 9P (network) protocol driver.

Comment: Does it use `host:` or `host::` specification? If not, then `rsync` considers it to be a local (on-machine) copy. That's why using `rsync` over SMB or NFS is way less efficient than talking directly to the target host

Comment: @roaima That's a good point - The local drives are mounted network filesystems, but `rsync` probably doesn't know that.  Oh well, like I said, I was *"taking a bit of a guess"* since it was late and I didn't have a chance to test it out on my end.  I would still say it's worthwhile to test with WSL2, since it is faster in general when dealing with Windows files, but I was thinking that most of that slowdown in the OP's results was probably due to the delta calculations, but I agree -- That's probably not in play here based on your comment.

Comment: Good guess @NotTheDr01ds. The source is `/mnt/c/`, the target is `/mnt/w/`. WSL2's slow file access does not explain why `rsync /mnt/c/ to ssh` is 10x faster than `rsync /mnt/c to /mnt/w` - it should be also super slow, not? I also tried `-W`, it did not help. If the diff returns only 78 files out of 17k - does rsync actually compare files if they have the same size and timestamp (within +-2 seconds of tolerance)?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and hint to use wsl1. Microsoft confirms your observations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#exceptions-for-using-wsl-1-rather-than-wsl-2

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek Right - I'm very hopeful that you'll see a drastic improvement with WSL1.  I'll noodle some more on the "why" in this scenario - I have a hunch, but I want to test it out before posting it.  I'll update the answer when/if I know more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with slow WSL accessing a mounted hard drive in my case was one folder with 21000 files (no subfolders).

`time ls -lR` measured from to 2 to 3 minutes - just to list the contents of that folder.

When I moved those files into subfolders with up to 7000 files each, `time` measured just 15 seconds and `rsync` runs much faster now ;).